# How to use a select query inside an insert query in values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
insert into patient_record(patient_no, patient_name, datetime_of_birth, 
                           GP_unique_no, GP_name, GP_address,complaint,
                           treatment, doctor, datetime_treatment_started, 
                           datetime_treatment_ended)

values(13, 'Sophie', '1955-05-13', 'G202',
       **select name_of_doctor from gp_doctor where unique_no=G202**,
       'Yorkshire', 'Broken right arm', 'Plaster Arm', 'Peter Parker',
       '2012-01-25','2012-01-29')
```

I don't know how to add `G202`. any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asuming unique_no is unique, you can select that record to get the name

```
insert into patient_record(patient_no, patient_name, datetime_of_birth, 
                           GP_unique_no, GP_name, GP_address,complaint,
                           treatment, doctor, datetime_treatment_started, 
                           datetime_treatment_ended)

SELECT
   13, 
   'Sophie', 
   '1955-05-13', 
   'G202',
    name_of_doctor,
    'Yorkshire', 
    'Broken right arm', 
    'Plaster Arm', 
    'Peter Parker',
    '2012-01-25','2012-01-29'
FROM gp_doctor 
where unique_no = 'G202'
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do a subselect in the middle of an `INSERT` statement .... you need to do this before you run your `INSERT`:

```
DECLARE @GPName VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @GPName = name_of_doctor 
FROM dbo.gp_doctor 
WHERE unique_no = 'G202'  -- I assume this is really a *string* here for the "unique_no"

INSERT INTO 
   dbo.patient_record(patient_no, patient_name, datetime_of_birth, 
                      GP_unique_no, GP_name, GP_address, complaint,
                      treatment, doctor, datetime_treatment_started, 
                      datetime_treatment_ended)
VALUES
     (13, 'Sophie', '1955-05-13', 
      'G202', @GPName, 'Yorkshire', 'Broken right arm', 
      'Plaster Arm', 'Peter Parker', '2012-01-25','2012-01-29')
```

or something like that.